# Fluxx "Once during your turn" New Rule cards

Tags: fluxx

If I play a "New Rule" that allows an action "once during your turn" (Recycling, Goal Mill, etc.) - do I get to take those action immediately, or is my turn now over because I've completed my "played one".

I understand that new rules go into effect immediately, what I'm not clear on is exactly when my turn is over for the "once during your turn" clause.

Answer (score 4):

**New Rules take effect immediately. Your turn is over after you have completed all the required rules and you have chosen not to perform any optional actions.**

The [Online FAQ](http://wunderland.com/LooneyLabs/Fluxx/FAQ.html) and the rules both tell you that new rules take effect immediately (I didn't quote the rules pdf, but look under **New Rule:**, and also gives blue example boxes)

> *Q: Suppose the rule is Play 2 and for my second play I change the rules to Play 3. Do I play one more card or am I done because I played 2?*
>
> A: All rules take effect immediately, so you would need to play 1 more card because the rules at that point had become Play 3.

The turn order is described in [the rules](http://sf.looneylabs.com/literature/Fluxx4.0Rules.pdf)

> **On Your Turn:**
>
> 1) Draw the number of cards currently required.
>
> 2) Play the number of cards currently required.
>
> 3) Discard down to the current Hand Limit (if any).
>
> 4) Comply with the current Keeper limit (if any).
>
> **Optional actions allowed by New Rules, Keepers, etc may be performed at any point during this sequence.**

So for example, [Recycling](http://www.trollandtoad.com/p300326.html) is an optional rule that says,

> Once per turn, **you may** discard a Keeper you have on the table and Draw 3 extra cards.

You can choose to use its ability anytime during your turn sequence.

Comment: If there are no are no further cards to be played, and no cards or keepers to discard (steps 2&3&4 on the turn sequence), since the new rule played as the last play on step 2  does not have a required action - wouldn't that mean the turn is now over?  If so, one would not be able to opt to use the optional action on that rule until their next turn.

Comment: @Justin, No. There is a step 2,3,4 regardless if you are required to do anything or not. The way I understand "during" is that there a minimum of 3 points where you could choose to use an optional rule. Between steps 1-2, between 2-3, and between 3-4. Another possibilty is tbat the end-points are inclusive and you can use an optional rule before step 1, or after step 4, but that is uncertain in my reading of the rules.

Comment: I would say your turn is over. Once you've played that rule, you've played the one action card you are allowed per turn, and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

If you play the rule as your turn of one play then you can follow the rule as long as it says that it is a free action then you can complete the new rule and then you have ended your turn.